# Reagent Canvas Component

Tags: canvas, clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to write a reagent component, which abstracts over the fact that HTML Canvas elements need to have some absolute pixel sizes. I'd rather want to always use the canvas on the maximum resolution.

Finally, I'd use the component like this:

```
[Canvas {:width "100%"
         :height "100%"
         :render (fn [ctx [w h]]
                    (.fillRect ctx 0 0 (/ w 2) (/ h 2)))}]
```

And here's my approach:

```
(defn Canvas [{:keys [width height render]}]
  (let [state (r/atom {:size nil})
        update-size (fn [el]
                      (when el 
                        (let [size (get-real-size el)
                              ctx (.getContext el "2d")]
                          (swap! state assoc :size size)
                          (render ctx size))))]
    (fn []
      (let [{:keys [size]} @state]
         [:canvas {:style {:width width :height height} 
                   :ref update-size
                   :width (nth size 0)
                   :height (nth size 1)}]))))
```

whereas:

```
(defn get-real-size [el]
  (let [bb (.getBoundingClientRect el)]
    [(.-width bb) (.-height bb)]))
```

The canvas seems to be rendered correctly with the corresponding size. But the render function does not draw anything. Does anybody know how to fix/handle this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't get any drawing is that your component is rendered before it's mounted. In order to fix that you have to turn rendering once again after it is mounted.

Here is how [reagent manual explains this](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-cookbook/tree/master/recipes/canvas-fills-div). Although it presents a solution to the problem of redrawing after the window dimensions have changed, but the solution applies to you as well.

In your case you can easily trigger rerendering by dereferencing an atom.

```
(defn Canvas [{:keys [width height render]}]
    (let [state (atom nil)]
        (reagent/create-class
            {:reagent-render      (fn []
                                      (let [update-size (fn [el]
                                                            (when el
                                                                (let [size (get-real-size el)
                                                                      ctx (.getContext el "2d")]
                                                                    (swap! state assoc :size size)
                                                                    (render ctx size))))]
                                          (fn [] (let [{:keys [size]} @state]
                                                     [:canvas {:style  {:width width :height height}
                                                               :ref    update-size
                                                               :width  (nth size 0)
                                                               :height (nth size 1)}]))))
             :component-did-mount (fn [] (reset! state {:size nil}))
             })))
```